# Microservices application on Heroku free plan

Tags: heroku, microservices

Whether it's possible to create application consists of some microservices on Heroku free plan when I have only 1 free dyno?

Is it correct each microservice has to be deployed as 1 Heroku app? Does it mean it's possible to run only 1 Heroku app on 1 dyno or I can run may Heroku apps (many microservices) on 1 free dyno?

Comment: One microservice per dyno; you can only expose one port. If you want to run it within a single dyno, maybe the microservice architecture isn't the right choice?

Comment: "when I have only 1 free dyno"—why do you only have one free dyno? Heroku lets you run several free dynos if you want.

Comment: @Chris interesting... where I can read about this? How many free dynos I can launch?

Comment: I'm not sure that there's much to read, but feel free to search. I'd just try spinning a new one up and see what happens. Each of your microservices would be a different app. I think you can have up to five apps, each with a single free dyno, on an unverified account and many more if you verify. (Don't think about this in terms of dynos. Think in terms of apps.)